# angular resolver does not have access to angular service properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

i have an anagular service called authservice ,which looks like this:

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
   public DecdedToken: any;
   userToken: any;
  public  userid: any;
      helper: any = new JwtHelperService();
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/';
    // userToken: any;
 constructor(private http: Http , private jwthelpservicee: JwtHelperService) {}
    login(model: any) {
      return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, this.requestOptions()).map((response: Response) => {
          const user = response.json();
          if (user && user.stringToken) {
              this.userToken = user.stringToken;
              localStorage.setItem('token', user.stringToken);
              this.DecdedToken = this.helper.decodeToken(user.stringToken);
              this.userid = this.DecdedToken.nameid;
             // console.log(this.userid);
               // onsole.log('so far so good');
          }
      }).catch(this.HandleError);
    }

    register(model: any) {
     return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', model, this.requestOptions()).catch(this.HandleError);
    }
    private requestOptions() {
      const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
      return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
    IsLoggedIn() {
      return !this.jwthelpservicee.isTokenExpired();
  }
    private HandleError(error: any) {
      const applicationerror = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
      if (applicationerror) {
        return Observable.throw(applicationerror);

      }
      const serverError = error.json();
      let modelStateErrors = '';
      if (serverError) {
        for (const key in serverError) {
          if (serverError[key]) {
            modelStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
          }
        }
      }
     return Observable.throw(modelStateErrors || 'server error');
    }
  }
```

in login method DecodedToken gets its value.
i have a resolver too, in which i am trying to get a value of a property from authsercvice

```
import { Resolve, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/router';
import { User } from '../_Models/user';
import { Injectable } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../_services/User.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class MemberEditResolver implements Resolve<User> {

    constructor(private userservice: UserService ,
         private router: Router ,
          private alertify: AlertifyService,
          private authservice: AuthService) {

    }
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User> {
        console.log(this.authservice.userid);
     return   this.userservice.getuser(this.authservice.DecdedToken.nameid).catch(error => {

            this.alertify.error('error');
            this.router.navigate(['/members']);
            return Observable.of(null);
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see i have defined DecdedToken as a public property, inside the authservice  this property has value, but when i want to access it from resolver ,i get null or undefined...

Comment: Are you sure your resolver doesn‘t access this value too early? Did you check it with console.log()? What happens if you try to get DectedToken itself and not one of its internal fields? Is the outcome still null?

Comment: yeah i tried it before posting the problem ,decodedtoken is null either

Comment: What prints `console.log(this.authservice.userid);` in your Resolver?

Comment: all i get is null